# Live Wallpaper onOffsetsChanged not called in custom Home application? Android

Tags: android, live-wallpaper

I am implementing a live wallpaper for android. I observed that the onOffsetsChanged(float xOffset, float yOffset, float xStep, float yStep, int xPixels, int yPixels) can be used to check the current live screen on the home application. How ever there are some custom home application like the ADW Home app, that does not call the onOffsetsChanged as expected. In my phone when I replace ADW with default home app, the onOffsetsChanged is called correctly. How do i over come this issue, so that my live wallpaper works fine with this ADW launcher also. Please let me know any knid of alternative if possible also. Thank you.